# How do we calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(e^{x} + 2x\right)^{3/x}$ using L'Hôpital?

Tags: calculus

How do we calculate the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(e^{x} + 2x\right)^{3/x}
\end{align*}
using L'Hôpital?
I don't understand how to differentiate and evaluate the limit.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. If you are expecting people to help you, you should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question. Also, you really need to show that you have put some effort into solving the problem. Not only is this not a homework-doing site, but also when you can talk sensibly about what you've tried and where you are stuck, it's easier for people to give you useful hep.

Comment: $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$

Comment: Let $y=\left(e^{x}+2 x\right)^{\frac{3}{x}}$,
then $\ln y=\frac{3}{x} \ln \left(e^{x}+2 x\right).$ Take limit and then use L’Hospital.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously we can\t use l'Hopital\s Rule right away. But we can use it on
$$
y=\ln(e^x+2x)^{3/x}=3\frac{\ln(e^x+2x)}{x}
$$
Since the limits of the denominator and numerator are both $0$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to0}y&=&3\lim_{x\to0}\frac{[\ln(e^x+2x)]'}{(x)'}\cr
&=&3\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^x+2}{e^x+2x}}{1}\cr
&=&3\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+2}{e^x+2x}\cr
&=&9
\end{eqnarray}
Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}y=9$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}(e^x+2x)^{3/x}=e^{\lim_{x\to0}y}=e^9.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

\begin{align}
&\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}~(e^x+2x)^{3/x}\\
=&\exp\left[\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}~\frac{3}{x}\ln(e^x+2x)\right]\\
=&\exp\left[3\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}~\frac{\ln(e^x+2x)}{x}\right]\\
=&\exp\left[3\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}~\left(\frac{e^x+2}{e^x+2x}\right)/1\right]~~~(\text{L'Hôpital's rule})\\
=&e^9\\
\end{align}